# Ansible : weirdness with jinja2_native=True

Tags: ansible, templating, ansible-bug

I have to switch to `jinja2_native=True`, and some of my json_queries do not work anymore.

Playbook :

```yaml
- name: Test JMESpath
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars:
    name_to_find: "someName"
    name_to_find2: "someOtherName"
    type_to_find: "someType"


  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "query={{ query }}"
      vars:
        query: "[? (name == '{{ name_to_find }}' || name == '{{ name_to_find2 }}') && type == '{{ type_to_find }}' ]"
```

Output :

```
[bzjr2686@tower ansible-dev]$ ansible-playbook play-test_types.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [Test JMESpath] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "query=[? (name == 'someName || name == someOtherName) && type == someType' ]"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Output before jinja2_native :

```
[bzjr2686@tower ansible-dev]$ ansible-playbook play-test_types.yml
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [Test JMESpath] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "query=[? (name == 'someName' || name == 'someOtherName') && type == 'someType' ]"
}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Where are the single quotes gone ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in jinja versions < 2.11
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/69242

Comment: Jinja 2.10 was released about 5 years ago. It's about time to upgrade. With such a version for Jinja2, I suspect your ansible version is outdated as well. As of today, the current version of ansible (6.3.0 distributed with ansible-core 2.13.3) requires Jinja2 >= 3.0.0

Comment: Sorry, my IT department only ships RHEL8. I use what is in the EPEL REPO : ansible 2.9.21-1.el8 and python3-jinja2 2.10.1-2.el8_0

Comment: remove the rpm package for ansible and jinja then install through pip which is the recommended install method and you will get the lastest version.

Answer (score 0):

- [JmesPath](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#grammar) wants a literal to be quoted in back-ticks

```
literal           = "`" json-value "`"
```

- *query* is reserved name. Please don't use it as a name of a variable. Otherwise, you should see

```
[WARNING]: Found variable using reserved name: query
```

- Use [folded style](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#813-folded-style) to make a long query better readable

```yaml
    _query: >
      [?(name == `{{ name1 }}` ||
         name == `{{ name2 }}`) &&
         type == `{{ type }}`]
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    name1: n1
    name2: n2
    type: A

    test:
      - {name: n1, type: A}
      - {name: n2, type: A}
      - {name: n9, type: A}
      - {name: n1, type: X}
      - {name: n2, type: X}
      - {name: n9, type: X}

    result: "{{ test|json_query(_query) }}"
    _query: >
      [?(name == `{{ name1 }}` ||
         name == `{{ name2 }}`) &&
         type == `{{ type }}`]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: result|to_yaml
```

both ANSIBLE_JINJA2_NATIVE true/false give the same result

```yaml
  result:
    - {name: n1, type: A}
    - {name: n2, type: A}
```